# How long does it take to get bitcoin trough Twitter

Tags: bitcoin-core

My friend @JayeCane , that's his Twitter nickname also, sent me BTC through Twitter at my address : bc1qhl8ajxff5z4zmmsshsnz98m3x7r2lupsuvfjeq
before 4 day's ago.
I have to wait or something went wrong?
What information you need to help me out ?
Thanks for advice.

Comment: Twitter cannot transfer BTC

Comment: Hi Nani, as others have pointed out, Twitter doesn't facilitate Bitcoin transactions. It sounds as if you may have sent your friend a payment request via Twitter, but I don't see indication of an unconfirmed transaction on the network that is attempting to pay this address. Your best course of action is to follow up with your friend and ask whether they've made the payment and whether they could give you the transaction id to track it.

Answer (score 1):

No money has been sent to your address since January

See any blockchain explorer. For example https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/bc1qhl8ajxff5z4zmmsshsnz98m3x7r2lupsuvfjeq

Your twitter friend either made a mistake, perhaps too low a transaction fee, or didn't actually send any money. Your friend should be able to provide the Transaction-Id for the transaction in which the payment was made. You can then look that up in a blockchain explorer if it doesn't show up in your own wallet.

Comment: Hey, Thank you a lot for this info, I just didn't know where to look at, I was there but confused and this is all I needed. Thanks for your time ✌️